# Quantization noise in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm recording some voice in MATLAB and then quantizing it down from 16-bit to 1-bit so I can calculate the SNR but I'm not getting reasonable SNR figures. Anyone point me in the right direction?

```
% Store recorded audio signal in numeric array
signal = getaudiodata(recording, 'int16');

quanRate = 16;
quantsignal = signal;

while quanRate ~= 1
 quanRate = quanRate - 1;

 quantsignalHold = quantsignal;

 % Remove LSB using bitshift
 quantsignal = bitshift(quantsignal, -1);

 % Plot the quantized signal
 figure()
 plot(quantsignal);
 title(['Sample recording at ' num2str(quanRate) '-bits']);
 xlabel('Sample number') % x-axis label
 ylabel('Sample value') % y-axis label

 % Calculate the quantisation error 
 quantError = quantsignal - signal; 

 % Calculate the SNR
 SNR = snr(signal,quantError); 

 disp(['The SNR of the ' num2str(quanRate) '-bit recording is: ' num2str(SNR) ' dB'])
end
```

Comment: Please describe more reasonable SNR figure.

Answer (score 2):

By shifting the samples of your signal to the right, you are dividing it by 2. The difference between this quantized signal and the original is always half the signal amplitude, not the quantization error.

You might want to instead quantize with

```
floor( signal / N ) * N + N/2;
```

or something similar (with `N` a power of two that increases every loop iteration).